# Why is Guice throwing a NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, guice

This is the Google Guice calling code:

```
public static ContainerRunner forInjector(Injector injector) {
    return (ContainerRunner)injector.getInstancefaultContainerRunner.class);
}

public static ContainerRunner forModules(Iterable<? extends Module> modules) {
    return forInjector(Guice.createInjector(modules));
}
```

And this the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.requestInjection(Lcom/google/inject/internal/InjectorImpl;Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/google/inject/Binding;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Set;)Lcom/google/inject/internal/Initializable;
at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor$1.visit(BindingProcessor.java:108)
at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor$1.visit(BindingProcessor.java:70)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInstanceBindingImpl.acceptTargetVisitor(ProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor.visit(BindingProcessor.java:70)
at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor.visit(BindingProcessor.java:43)
at com.google.inject.internal.BindingImpl.acceptVisitor(BindingImpl.java:93)
at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:56)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:186)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
at com.baml.gmt.xasf.container.ContainerRunners.forModules(ContainerRunners.java:39)
```

**My problem is that the message does not tell me which particular method is missing.  Is there a good way to debug this?  Can this be a Maven transitive dependency issue?**

Answer (score 0):

It tells you exactly what method is missing. It's:

- package `com.google.inject.internal.Initializer`

  - [`Initializable requestInjection(InjectorImpl, Object, Binding, Object, Set)`](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/Initializer.java#L76)

Considering that method signature was last changed [Five years ago](https://github.com/google/guice/commit/bf2b16c06a5ff7c099fe60f9a46cfb130ce45962), you almost certainly have some sort of build issue that is making the method not be in your classpath somehow. You haven't given us enough information to be able to debug further.

Comment: Thank you, @durron597, the message is not consistent.  I was told that it could be caused by multiple Guice versions pulled via transitive dependencies.  What is killing me is that this error message hints nowhere to start with.  Or it could be because multiple versions of any jars existing.

Comment: I just ran the same main method in two places: IntelliJ and Unix, where in the lib directory I dump all dependency files generated by mvn dependency:copy-dependencies and pub lib as java classpath.  In IntelliJ, it runs fine.  In Unix, it threw this error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that, when I executed in Unix environment, there were permission issue with the files in lib directory.  As soon as I changed the permission, it got past this Guice error.  This Guice error, from my paste experience, is almost always due to dependency issues, one way or the other.  But Guice does not give you a more specific, more descriptive error message.